# Visualizing encrypted image without saving decrypted version

Tags: encryption, gpg

I am learning how to decrypt secret image files using gpg.
In the example below I am encrypting (and then visualizing) a photo called `kermit.png`.
So far I was able to do this as follows:

```
gpg -d kermit.png.gpg >> kermit_decrypted.png
xdg-open kermit_decrypted.png
```

Now the problem is that I do not want to save a decrypted version of my image, because then I will have to remember to delete it using `shred -u kermit_decrypted.png` or something of this sort.
Instead, I would prefer to simply pipe the output of `gpg -d kermit.png.gpg` into an image viewer.
Of course the issue is that my image viewer (`viewnior`) does not accept this output as its input.

How to go around this?

Comment: Check here https://superuser.com/questions/247880/is-there-an-image-viewer-that-takes-images-on-stdin

Answer (score 4):

You can use `feh`:

```bsh
$ gpg -d kermit.png.gpg | feh -
```

There's also `fim`:

```bsh
$ gpg -d kermit.png.gpg | fim -i
```

And the command `display` from `imagemagick`:

```bsh
$ gpg -d kermit.png.gpg | display
```

Comment: Take care: some picture viewers might create a preview or thumbnail ....

Comment: @pLumo I think in `fim` and `feh` you have to explicity pass an option fot thumbnails, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Any idea if `display` creates a thumbnail?

Comment: Also: what about for videos? (I know this is slightly out of the scope of the question, but it seems overkill to create a new question for video files...)